# Updating the kernel on a Linux Mint Live USB

Tags: linux, linux-mint, iso-image, kernel, liveusb

I'm following this guide: https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1784
to update a Linux Mint ISO. Specifically, I'd like to update the kernel of this version of Mint to 4.4.8.

For kernel installation the guide I linked to points to this other guide: https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1718

and the kernel files I'm using are from here:
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.8-wily/

I've followed the steps twice now and both times the resulting ISO isn't recognized as bootable when I load it on a flash drive, for reasons unclear.

Are there any steps that seem incorrect here?

Comment: There are some mostly automatic tools that can try creating a live ISO, remastersys may be abandoned but it has successors / forks

Comment: I gave remastersys and systemback a try. Both made live usbs that wouldn't boot. From more research I've gathered that it's related to newer kernels not having built in support for live CD/USB capabilities. Apparently that functionality is packaged in the kernels for the specific distros, but not in the general kernel.... So that's where I am. I'm looking into patching support for live USB functionality into the updated kernel.

Comment: Interesting, I did not know that. There must be a way to add the "live" bits to a kernel, especially if you're building it from source. I think Debian has pages & pages of advice & guides on building everything, and Ubuntu should say something about their own kernel builds, I've never tried it though

Comment: @Ethan did you solve this issue?

Comment: I didn't have any luck doing this unfortunately :/. I wanted to do this to make sure that the updated kernel in Linux Mint 18 would work with a laptop I was thinking of getting. I ended up just waiting for LM 18 to come out and trying it directly.